# Doctrine joined table inheritance without discriminator

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm

I have two objects, `Company (id, name)` and `CompanyWithAccount(accountNumber, balance) extends Company`.

If I use `InheritanceType("JOINED")`, i have to specify `DiscriminatorColumn`. In this column is stored flag, that specifies, if it is `Company` or `CompanyWithAccount`, but I want, to able be both.

For example:
`$company = $em->find('Company', 1);`
create query:
`SELECT * FROM company WHERE id = 1;`
and
`($company instanceof Company)` is true

and

`$company = $em->find('CompanyWithAccount', 1);`
create query:
`SELECT * FROM company_with_account INNER JOIN company WHERE id = 1;`
and
`($company instanceof CompanyWithAccount)` is true

I don't need to specify discriminator, because row #1 can be `Company`, but also can be `CompanyWithAccount` if exist matching row in table `company_with_account`.

Is it something like this possible with Doctrine 2?